# How to test recyclerview using espresso with test data, no from api or database

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I am writing a test on recyclerview using espresso, As activity is launched it fetches data from database / API and then assert but in actual scenario I should test recyclerview with test data, I am not able to find any Blog/Post/Documentation where I can test my recyclerview with **Test Data**.

its been so long since users using espresso  but still couldn't find useful something useful for testing recyclerview with test data.

I am using mvvm, dagger2 and jetpack in kotlin.

Please help me If there is any Blog, Post or Documentation which I can follow.

Answer (score 0):

By Espresso you can access your activity. Suppose your `recyclerView` and `adapter` are initialized. And let you set adapter in your recyclerView at early stage may be `onCreate()` or `onResume()` . But yet you have no item in `adapter` mean `recyclerView` item count 0.

So think in your Espresso test. You can access your `recyclerView` by using

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.our_recycler_view);
```

I think you know about `activityRule`. Now you get adapter from your recyclerView . `recyclerView.getAdapter();`

**Create a list of fake/dummy item** and add your adapter. Wait some millisecond and start operation on your `recyclerView`